# Making image full screen on android tutorial app

Tags: android, imageview

Using the Hello, World Gridview tutorial example, I am attempting to make the image fullscreen on click instead of display the position of the image in the array.  As I am unfamilar with Android and this is my first development attempt with it, I'm at a loss.  I am familiar with Java though, and I've tried doing things like this (that don't work obviously):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            showImage(v, position);
            Toast.makeText(HelloAndroid.this, "" + parent.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void showImage(View view, int position) {
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view; 
    imgView.setImageResource(position);     
}
```

But the app crashes (force close).  Any ideas?

[Here is the tutorial app I am using](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

Comment: What is the exact error you get?  What does LogCat say?

Comment: It's throwing a null pointer at imgView.setImageResource.  Thanks for the tip about logcat, I was just using the regular debugger.  At least now I can see verbose errors :)  view.getId() is -1 btw.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
imgView.setImageResource(position);
```

This gives you an error because you are not using it correctly. The parameter should be pointing to the resource ID of the image (which is an int) e.g. `R.id.imageid`. Even if you were to supply the right resource ID, what you want to do would not work.

To get the right resource ID, you would need to call the adapter of the view and use the `getItemId(position)` method to get the correct resource ID. in your ImageAdapter, if you change your `getItemId()` method to return `mThumbsIds[position]` rather than 0 (as in Google's example).

However, to achieve your result I would suggest for you to create a new Activity and just load the image like that.

For example:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        long imageId = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter.getItemAt(position);

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FullScreenImage.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra(thisClassName.class.getName(), imageId);

        thisClassName.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
    }
});
```

Assuming you create a `full_image.xml` layout file, containing just an ImageView with an id of `"fullImage"`, your FullScreenImage class should look like this:

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        long imageId = intent.getExtras().get(thisClassName.class.getName());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fullImage);

        imageView.setLayoutParams( new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
}
```

Something along these lines should work well for you, with some tweaking. Make sure you add FullScreenImage in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file as an `<activity>` as well.

Comment: Needed some editing but I got the gist of it once I started on it.  I probably should have started with something a little easier jumping into Android :p

Comment: long imageId = (ImageAdapter)parent.getAdapter.getItemAt(position); -- this line shows me Type mismatch: cannot convert from MainActivity.ImageAdapter to long

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're taking the ID of the view that was *clicked* (passed in the `view` argument) and using it to look up itself again:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(view.getId());
```

That makes no sense, especially since the clicked view apparently *has* no ID, causing `findViewById` to return `null`.

You probably want to pass the ID of your `ImageView` instead:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.whatever_the_id_of_the_image_view_is);
```

Comment: v is my ImageView though, I double checked in the debugger and it's showing up there ok, but it doesn't have an mID (which seem to be the id, since that's what shows up if I try parent.getId().  The ImageView is a dynamic object generated inside the code and is the data makeup of the GridView if that helps any.

Comment: I'm getting closer, now the image is becoming blank and I'm not getting an error.

Comment: Since the imageView is inside the gridview, do I have to replace the gridview?

Comment: I've updated the code to show a larger portion of what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm guessing you now get a ClassCastException, because you misinformed me. I've rolled back to my previous answer, which was correct. If it doesn't work for you, report the exact exception and line number.