# Android : show an image after clicking a button

Tags: android, image, button, onclick, click

I am looking for this for 2 days. I can't figure out how can i show an image( in my res folder) How can i show an image after clicking a button?

Comment: You should supply a little more information: How do you want to display it, perhaps include the code (part) that is not working...

Comment: i want to show an image in my res folder after clicking a button i wrote this View.OnClickListener schedule = new View.OnClickListener() {    public void onClick(View v) {// i dont know what i must write here?} how can i be more specific?

Comment: Where you would like to show it would be veery helpful... ImageView, in a ImageView in a Dialog... ;)

Comment: i just want to show image to user in fullscreen i dont know how to use ImageView etc. so i ask the question :)

Comment: user1248643 you can use this this is, here s3 is a object of radio button   S3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Activity One:

```
public class TestbuttontestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.widget45);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) { 
             Intent inf=new Intent(TestbuttontestActivity.this,Activityfullscreen.class);

             startActivity(inf);
            }
          });
    }
}
```

Activity Two:

```
public class Activityfullscreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calc);
       ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.widget45);
       img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.digitallovesaktid);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TestbuttontestActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:name="Activityfullscreen"></activity>
    </application>
```

Activity One Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/widget45"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
         />
         <TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget45"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Two Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget45"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />


</LinearLayout>
```

***AND second and best  way use popupwindow and two layout one for main activity and another for popupwindow***:

```
private void showpopup()
    {
       LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
       View mView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.lnparentpopup));
       PopupWindow mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(mView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, false);
       mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);

       TextView TV=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtmain);          
      // TableLayout L1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblntarialview);

       mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(TV, Gravity.CENTER, 45, 0);

     }
```

this code will show you an image in full screen when user press button and  what you want apart from this please share your code....

Comment: thanks i will try this. if i want to show an image fullscreen i must create two activity. i can't show image with a method. Am i get it right?

Comment: thanks,but i think one more way by using popupwindow can you try it otherwise i will try for u...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, please note first that there are [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial) and documentation (such as for [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)) on the Android website, as well as sample programs all over the web.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916987/151682) shows you how to combine such a tutorial and a fullscreen option.

Usually, an image is displayed in an ImageView. Which method you call depends on how your image is available: If you added it as a static resource to your project, you can use `setImageResource(int resId)`. If you have downloaded it as a bitmap or drawable, use the according setX methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: arent there any method like setBackground() to show an image? is the only way the viewing an image creating a new class?

Comment: I have not tried it so far, but there is such a [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) in the View class. But you should ask yourself whether you want to set the background of something to an image and put something over it - or just want to display the image plain and simple (-> ImageView)

Comment: it shows my image but as a background so i can see other buttons on my image. is there any method to show full image not as a background?

Comment: I am sorry, but you are mixing stuff up a bit. If you want to "overlay" the image over everything else, best use a new activity as described in the link in my answer above.