# How to set size to full screen?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery, android-image

I'm using the source code from [this tutorial]

And I want to make all the full screen when I display them.

How do I do it?

Comment: [Use a different `ScaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915312/making-image-full-screen-on-android-tutorial-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your theme in AndroidManifest.xml for your app to be full screen. Your ImageView to be fill parent or match parent and your root view to match entire screen.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work